# Handle double quotes inside the field value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a row like below in a csv file

```
"1"|"A "Great" Experience"|"T"
```

When I read this using below code

```
pandas.read_csv(file2Name,sep = '|',keep_default_na=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

it gives the output as: `[1,A Great" Experience",T]`

I need the output as : `[1,A "Great" Experience,T]`

Tried many ways using using various parameters to it.
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`pd.read_csv` function has parameter `quotechar`:

> quotechar : str (length 1), optional
>
> The character used to denote the start and end of a quoted item. Quoted
>   items can include the delimiter and it will be ignored.

You can change the default value `"` by smth else, for example `~`, and after that remove `"` from field edges:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file2Name, sep="|", quotechar="~")
df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip("\""))
```

Answer (score -1):

`"` is taken as quoting character. So try escaping it using `/`.

Make the following change:

`"1"|"A "Great" Experience"|"T"` changes to `"1"|"A /"Great/" Experience"|"T"`

Perform `read_csv` operation:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file2Name, sep='|', quotechar='"',escapechar="/")
```